# How to log SQL batch queries in a file

Tags: mysql

Let's say I run a query in MySQL

mysql> delete from subscriber where mobile in (9899347241);
Query OK, 2 rows affected, 18 warnings (32.91 sec)

So now I have a abc.sql which contains no. of such delete, update sql's and I run it using

```
mysql -h host -u user -p < abc.sql > output.txt
```

I have tried different options like --verbose, --tee. None seems to log the info text
Query OK, 2 rows affected, 18 warnings (32.91 sec)

How can i log this. Basically when I have run the batch file, I want to be able to see if each query ran ok. One way for me to do this is to include a select query before and after the delete/update but there must be a better way to see if queries ran successfully.

Comment: Could be writing those messages to STDERR instead of STDOUT. Try adding `2>&1` to redirect stderr so it can be captured.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

-vvv is the solution to what we are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

`2>&1` is what you are looking for